# Why is this constructor being called 3 times when passing to std::thread?

Tags: c++, multithreading

Consider this snippet of code:

```
class Widget {
public:
   Widget() { coutDefaultCtor();  }
   Widget(const Widget& w) { coutCopyCtor(); }
   Widget(Widget&& w) {  coutMoveCtor(); }

  ~Widget() = default; 

  void coutDefaultCtor() {
      std::cout << " called default Widget ctor " << std::endl;
  }

  void coutMoveCtor() {
      std::cout << " called move Widget ctor " << std::endl;
  }

  void coutCopyCtor() {
      std::cout << " called copy Widget ctor " << std::endl;
  }

  void doSomething() const { }
};

void takeWidget(const Widget& ref) {
  ref.doSomething();
}

int main() {
   Widget widget;

   std::thread t(takeWidget, widget);
   t.join();
   // expect 2 ctor calls
   // but calls 3
}
```

As far as I know, `std::thread` will always copy the arguments by value.
If in a case the entry point function is defined as taking an r-value or const l-value reference (same thing here), internally a temporary of the type will be created an be passed as r-value.

The output of the above code prints, `" called Widget ctor "` 3 times.
One for every constructor, default, copy and move.

I was expecting only 2 times, one for the `widget` default constructor being called in `main()` and the temporary that is created by `std::thread` which in turn is moved, why is another seemingly extra construction happening here?

Comment: It would help if you printed out a different message for each constructor, as well as a message for the destructor. That will give you a better idea of when each constructor is called and when each object is destroyed

Comment: All 3 are called once.

Comment: You can get away with a single ctor and dtor call by doing a `std::thread t(takeWidget, std::ref(widget));` Read examples https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread for more details

Comment: @cplusplusrat Of course, but I really want to understand why this example calls 3 when it should call 2 constructors.

Comment: @MosheRabaev how do you know all three are being called, if your logging doesn't differentiate between them? Did you step through the code line by line with a debugger?

Comment: I tested it, will update the example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's an implementation detail of the C++ standard library and is probably different in different implementations. There is more going on in `std::thread t(takeWidget, widget)` than simply calling `takeWidget(widget)`. For example, in the GCC implementation, the `thread` constructor calls `make_tuple()` which would move or copy the parameters depending on their types.